# Add line "component $c set_parameter" only where there no spacing at beginning in a.cfg file

Tags: shell-script

I have attached a .cfg file.

```
BK = 2
CM = 2
LEF_M1_NAME = "ME1"
LEF_M2_NAME = "ME2"
LEF_M3_NAME = "ME3"
LEF_M4_NAME = "ME4"
LEF_M5_NAME = "ME5"
NB = 144
NW = 256
viewselect = {
              "alf"
              "allpvt"
              "allpvthtml"
              "atpg_netlist"
              "clp"
              "coord"
              "core"
              "cpf"
              "ctl"
              "dssum"
              "fast_func_verilog"
              "fastscan"
              "frontend_gds"
              "gds"
              "ikos"
              "lvlib"
              "masis"
              "verilog_vhd_stim"
              "chd_rtl"
             }
```

Now, I have to add `component $c set_parameter` line at the beginning of each line using `sed` command in Linux except where is a space at the beginning like `alf`, `allpvt` having space at the beginning and I do not want to add line `component $c set_parameter` over there. Can anybody help me for `sed` command syntax?

I have used the below `sed` command which print `component $c set_parameter` throughout all the lines.

```
sed -i -e 's/^/  component $c set_parameter /' a.cfg
```

The output of the command is as below

```
component $c set_parameter BK 2
component $c set_parameter CM 2
component $c set_parameter LEF_M1_NAME ME1
component $c set_parameter LEF_M2_NAME ME2
component $c set_parameter LEF_M3_NAME ME3
component $c set_parameter LEF_M4_NAME ME4
component $c set_parameter LEF_M5_NAME ME5
component $c set_parameter NB 144
component $c set_parameter NW 256
```

```
component $c set_parameter viewselect = {
component $c set_parameter               alf
component $c set_parameter               allpvt
component $c set_parameter               allpvthtml
component $c set_parameter               atpg_netlist
component $c set_parameter               clp
component $c set_parameter               coord
component $c set_parameter               core
component $c set_parameter               cpf
component $c set_parameter               ctl
component $c set_parameter               dssum
component $c set_parameter               fast_func_verilog
component $c set_parameter               fastscan
component $c set_parameter               frontend_gds
component $c set_parameter               gds
component $c set_parameter               ikos
component $c set_parameter               lvlib
component $c set_parameter               masis
component $c set_parameter               mask
component $c set_parameter               oasis
component $c set_parameter               params
component $c set_parameter               plef
component $c set_parameter               power_verilog
```

But I do not want `component $c set_parameter` line to be present at the beginning of `alf`, `allpvt` etc. all where it is spacing at the beginning.

I just want to print the line `component $c set_parameter` only where there are no spacing at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Search for any line that does not begin with a space character (using `^` in the character class to negate). For any match, substitute the start of the line for the "component" text.

`/^` search from start of string

`[^ .. ]` this is a character class, the `^` negates the contents of the class.

`[:space:]+` the character class is space or tab character

`[^[:space:]]+` but the class is negated, so search from the start of the string for at least one non-space character. (The `+` means at least one occurrence of a non-space character).

If a match is found in the `/.../` regex, do the following substitution - at the start of the string (^ means at start of string), add the "component..." text.

```
sed -E '/^[^[:space:]]+/ s/^/component $c set_parameter/' a.cfg
```

Comment: Hi! Can you please let me know about what  does it look for by using "^[^[:space:]]+/ " ?

Comment: Thanks for sharing this command

Comment: Will update the post to explain the sed command. If this post has solved your problem, please consider accepting it.